# Changing root logger level in submodule python

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

How can I change root logger level in it's submodule

```
#main.py
logging.basicConfig(filename=filename,format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',filemode='w')
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

After certain event I want to change all the logging to CRITICAL

```
sub_logger = logging.getLogger('jdm_health')
#submodule.py
if event:
    logger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)#root logger
```

Comment: Did you try `logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)` ?

Comment: yeah, but for some reason it's not working as expected.

Comment: what are you expecting, and what is happening? Please add that information to the question